# gotoAndStop takes the actions code of the frame where we are using the gotoAndStop method?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm with doubt hope you can help.
gotoAndStop takes the actions code of the frame where we are using the gotoAndStop method?
I'm asking this because i'm using `gotoAndStop(3)` in a actions of my first frame and when I go to the frame 3 because of my "`gotoAndStop(3)`" every code that I have in my first frame actions is working in my frame 3, but I dont want that, gotoAndStop works like this?
Is there any other option?

```
import Game;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

var game:Game = new Game(stage); 

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkScore);

game.statusGame(Game.status_begin);

function checkScore(e:Event)
   {
      if(game.pointsCount == 10)

        {
         gotoAndStop(3);
        }
    }
```

There is my code in the actions of first frame, now when i go to frame 3 this line of code "`game.statusGame(Game.status_begin);`" still working and i didnt want that and i dont have this code in my frame number 3!
In frame number 3 i just have this:

```
flash.ui.Mouse.show();

play_again_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, restartgame);

function restartgame(e:Event) 
{

 gotoAndStop("game");

}
```

My statusGame is where say to game begin and when i control the points to change for the next level, my code:

```
public function statusGame(status:int):void
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case 1 :
                    this.begin();
                    break;

                case 2 :
                    brokenBall = false;
                    ball = new Ball(this,velX,velY);
                    break;

                case 3 :
                    brokenBall = true;
                    points(); // to check points
                    break;

                case 4 :

                    velX = 15;
                    velY = -2;
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking for. Can you post some code with comments so we can better understand and help?

Comment: I post some code now!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the statusGame() method to continue into frame 3, then I would write a method that suppresses that method just before you move into frame 3, or in frame 3 I would check for that method and suppress it if it should not be running.
Something like this:

```
    function checkScore(e:Event)
    {
       if(game.pointsCount == 10){
        game.suppressionMethod();  //here is the method I was referring to
        gotoAndStop(3);
       }
    }
```

Comment: supressionMethod is a method of actionscript? because i dont find documentation in google. Or its a method that i need to create? The problem is that i know what´s wrong but i dont know how to "kill" or "supress" a variable or object, etc.

Comment: Yes, the suppression method is an abstract term for stopping the functionality that you do not wish to continue.  What is the code of statusGame() ?

Comment: i post that now, my idea is to create one more case that when i go the  the last level because pointsCount == 10 i want to stop the game, like kill the object or something but i´m not finding solution for that!